# In Node.js, what's "on"?

Tags: node.js, addeventlistener

In [official doc](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.3/api/http.html#http.ClientResponse), there is some sample code:

```
var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});
```

I can understand it except one part: what's `on` in `res.on`? What's the difference between it and `addListener`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's no different than `addListener`. There is some documentation on the event here: http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#emitter.on Both `on` and `addListener` are documented under the same heading. They have the same effect;

```
server.on('connection', function(stream) {
    console.log('someone connected!');
});

server.addListener('connection', function(stream) {
    console.log('someone connected!');
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Both `on` and `addListener` are aliases for the same function.

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation for Events](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.3/api/events.html#emitter.addListener) implies they're two aliases for the same function.